# RabbitMQ Колбек Получателя

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Начал изучать брокер сообщений RabbitMQ и остаются некоторые непонятные моменты!Грубо говоря есть 3 участника, Отправитель->Прослойка Queue MESSAGE->Получатель. Непонятно,что происходит под капотом у Отправителя в инициализации CreateConnection,CreateModel-там где прописывается хост сервера RabbitMQ,название сообщения,тело сообщения и булевы всякие?Соединение держится постоянно с сервером RabbitMQ путем Websocket или это единичный http Long pool запрос?Также в реализации клиентской части,есть callback,срабатывающий при получении message по его названию, какое время жизни этого callback, одно или вечно висит в коннекте с RabbitMQ?

Comment: зачем это знать? Это есть в доках? Пробовали декомпилировать клиент и поглядеть?

Comment: если вы хотите создать свой RabbitMQ брокер, тогда вопросы действительно интересные, если нет - достаточно документации https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html

Comment: Просто интересно, согласно документации, грубо говоря соединение с сервером RabbitMQ аналогично WebSocket протоколу? Просто везде описано, что это соединение долговечное,использующее просто аутентификацию!Там же нет такого как в http запросе,не посылается же из под капота каждый интервал времени слать запрос,верно? Вот и интересно,как там внутри организованно долгоживущее соединение?